# Test Software for Non-Standard Forms & Terminal Services

Tags: automated-testing

Is anyone aware of test software which:

- allows users to record test scripts (without requiring them to have programming knowledge).
- can "view" the screen rather than relying on apps which use a standard form & control libraries.

This second requirement is due to the following:

- We have some systems written in 4D (http://www.4d.com/), which uses its own forms (i.e. most test software can only see the main window; not sub windows).
- We have some systems which run over terminal services, which we'd ideally like to test over terminal services (as opposed to installing the test software on the terminal server, or having a fat client for testing).

Comment: There are image-based tools - Sikuli is one I've heard referenced but have never used.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Telerik Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/teststudio) for web applications. It doesn't require any knowledge of programming and has an intuitive interface. The test runner can be put on any of the VMs you might be using.

If it is not a web application, the only thing I have worked with would be [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) (which can have a steep learning curve).